# Can I copy an object in Java without modifying the class itself (like adding a copy constructor)?

Tags: java, copy-constructor

In my project I use an object from an external library, I need to make a copy of this object but I cannot modify the class in the library. How can I do that?

This is the class of the object that I must copy:

```
public class Tree<T> implements Iterable<Tree<T>> {
    private List<Tree<T>> children;
    private T value;
    private Tree<T> tree = this;

     ... 
    }
```

Comment: Does the object implements `Cloneable`, `Serializable` or something similar by any chance?

Comment: You can do by implementing Cloneable interfafce and implement clone method.

Comment: Why would you need to modify the class in the library to make a copy? Can't you just create another instance and set the appropriate values from the existing object? Please provide a minimum amount of code to be able to see what the problem actually looks like.

Comment: nope, i checked

Comment: [Do not use `Cloneable`, it is broken](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the class, implementing your specific object for your need, to which you can add the additional functionality.

Comment: I had thought about this,  but i must refacor the whole project

Comment: Only `in the cases` where you need to use this additional functionality.

Comment: If someone downvotes it is nice to give feedback also.

Comment: I don't think that will work as the class refers to itself, so it may call its own constructor. So even if you extend it, the original class won't create the subclass objects unless you override all of the methods calling the constructor. So then it is getting really messy.

Comment: @rghome When you need to use this additional functionality you will explicitly use the class that you created by extension.

Comment: The thing is, there is no reason to extend the class - it doesn't solve anything or add any advantage and it makes some things more complicated. Sure - you can add a copy constructor, but an external copy method would work as well and doesn't require an additional class.

Answer (score 1):

If the class doesn't implement Cloneable, there isn't a good way of doing this.

The acceptable way of doing it is just to write a utility method to copy the class manually, but that assumes you have some understanding of its internal structure.

For example, you can do a shallow copy as follows:

```
T newTree = new T();
for (T t : tree) {
    newTree.add(t);
}
```

But since your class contains sub-trees, those won't be copied; it would only be a shallow copy (the new tree would contain references to the subtrees in the old tree).

For a deep copy, you will have to recursively copy the subtrees as well. I don't really understand enough about the structure of your class to write code for it.